# Specify constructor arguments for a Google test Fixture

Tags: c++, unit-testing, constructor, googletest

With Google test I want to specify a Test fixture for use in different test cases.
The fixture shall allocate and deallocate objects of the class `TheClass` and its data management class `TheClassData`, where the data management class requires the name of a datafile.
For the different tests, the file name should vary.

I defined the following Fixture:

```
class TheClassTest : public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
  TheClassTest(std::string filename) : datafile(filename) {}
  virtual ~TheClassTest() {}
  virtual void SetUp() {
    data = new TheClassData(datafile);
    tc = new TheClass(data);
  }
  virtual void TearDown() {
    delete tc;
    delete data;
  }

  std::string datafile;
  TheClassData* data;
  TheClass* tc;
};
```

Now, different tests should use the fixture with different file names.
Imagine this as setting up a test environment.

**The question:** How can I specify the filename from a test, i.e. how to call a non-default constructor of a fixture?

I found things like `::testing::TestWithParam<T>` and `TEST_P`, which doesn't help, as I don't want to run one test with different values, but different tests with one fixture.

Comment: So you want to run that fixture yourself? The google test default test runner cannot instantiate fixtures with parameters.

Comment: I want to run a test (probably `TEST_F`) using the fixture. So the answer is, that it's not possible? Thanks.

Comment: I think `TestWithParam<T>` and `TEST_P` is exactly what you need. Lookup the [Advanced Docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md) how to use them in practice. You can always instantiate the instance under test (I assume it's `TheClass`) inside of the testcase.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As suggested by another user, you cannot achieve what you want
by instantiating a fixture using a non-default constructor. However,
there are other ways. Simply overload the `SetUp` function and
call that version explicitly in the tests:

```
class TheClassTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    TheClassTest() {}
    virtual ~TheClassTest() {}
    void SetUp(const std::string &filename) {
        data = new TheClassData(filename);
        tc = new TheClass(data);
    }
    virtual void TearDown() {
        delete tc;
        delete data;
    }

    TheClassData* data;
    TheClass* tc;
};
```

Now in the test simply use this overload to set up filename:

```
TEST_F(TheClassTest, MyTestCaseName)
{
    SetUp("my_filename_for_this_test_case");

    ...
}
```

The parameterless `TearDown` will automatically clean up when
the test is complete.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The SetUp method will still be called by gtest, resulting in two calls to SetUp ... so in this case there is a memory leak since TearDown only deletes the last allocations. I would rename SetUp to something else so that gtest does not call it.

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong. Since your `Setup` takes a parameter it won't be called by gtest. I would rename `SetUp` to something else since it can be confused with `SetUp()` which is called by gtest.

Answer (score 10):

Use the current class as a base class for your fixtures:

```
class TheClassTestBase : public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
  TheClassTestBase(std::string filename) : datafile(filename) {}
  ...
 };
```

For every specific filename - use derived fixture:

```
class TheClassTestForFooTxt : public TheClassTestBase {
protected:
    TheClassTestForFooTxt() : TheClassTestBase ("foo.txt") {}
};
```

However this is extra step needed for every set of parameters - so you can try to use templates or macros to get it done with less effort. Like:

```
template <typename ClassTestTag>
struct ClassTestParams
{
    static std::string filename;
};

template<typename  ClassTestTag>
class TheClassTest : public TheClassTestBase {
protected:
    TheClassTest() : TheClassTestBase (ClassTestParams<ClassTestTag>::filename) {}
};
```

Then - for every set of parameters - do that:

```
class FooTxtTag {};
template <> std::string ClassTestParams<FooTxtTag>::value = "foo.txt";
using TheClassTestForFooTxt = TheClassTest<FooTxtTag>;
TEST_F(TheClassTestForFooTxt, xxxx) {}
```

However - in your specific case - I would also try [GoogleTest:type-parameterized-tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#typed-tests).

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a bit too much effort for the size of my problem.

Comment: link to doc is broken

Answer (score 5):

Another great way to deal with this is to just extend your fixture and in the extended class supply a new default constructor which calls through to the old one with the arguments you require. For example:

```
struct MySpecializedTestFixture : public GenericTestFixture
{
  MySpecializedTestFixture() : GenericTestFixture("a thing", "another thing") {}
};

TEST_F(MySpecializedTestFixture, FancyTest)
{
  // Use the thing environment and make some assertions.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you overload the `SetUp` method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218657/276193), and you want to ensure that you remember to use the overloaded `SetUp`, you can use an assertion in the `TearDown` method.

```
class my_fixture : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    bool SETUP_HIT_FLAG = false;

    void SetUp(double parameter)
    {
        ...
        SETUP_HIT_FLAG = true;
    }

    void TearDown() override
    {
        assert(SETUP_HIT_FLAG && "You forgot to call SetUp with your parameter!");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using templates:

```
template<int N>
class Fixture : public ::testing::Test { ... }

using FixtureForTest = Fixture<1000>;
TEST_F(FixtureForTest, test) { ... }
```

Answer (score -3):

For this specific case, I feel it is much easier to get rid of the test fixture altogether. The `SetUp` function can instead be replaced with a helper function that instantiates the class with the required file name. This permits the use of `TEST` instead of `TEST_P` or `TEST_F`. Now each test case is a standalone test which creates its own test class instances with the helper function or directly in the body of the test case.

For example:

```
using namespace testing;
TEST(FooClassTest, testCase1)
{
    FooClass fooInstance("File_name_for_testCase1.txt");
    /* The test case body*/
    delete fooInstance;
}
```

Comment: The OP asked about using a test fixture. This example doesn't show how to reuse `datafile`, `data` and `tc`.  And what is up with `delete fooInstance` ?