# C++ Gtest how to pass parameter to a class fixture?

Tags: c++, googletest, ros, fixtures

I am a bit confused on how to pass parameter from main to the class fixture. Say I have:

```
#include "robot.h"
class Checksweep : public testing::Test{
public: 
  Checksweep(){}
  virtual void SetUp() {

    Robot1 = new Robot(&nh);
  }

  virtual void TearDown() { delete Robot1; }

  Robot *Robot1;

};

TEST_F(Checksweep, MyTestCaseName)
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  ros::init(argc, argv, "robot_test_node");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Are there anyway for me to send `nh` from `main()` to `setup()` in the `Checksweep` class?

Comment: It depends on what you need. If `nh` should be singleton (one object for all the tests), the you could just make it global object. If it may or should be recreated for every test suite/test case, then place it in either `SetUpTestSuite` or `SetUp`

Comment: I managed to work around this by putting ros::NodeHandle nh; inside the class. But I still would love to know if there is a way to send it from main to the class using SetUp. I thought SetUp can only be called in TEST_F?

Comment: I don't know of any way to pass something to the test class. GoogleTest hides all the magic it uses to instantiate and run every test. About SetUp, every `TEST_F` does the following: Create an instance of the test class -> call `SetUp()` on the instance -> execute test body -> call `TearDown` on the instance -> destroy instance. You should not call `SetUp` by yourself (although it shouldn't break the code in any way).

Comment: You can overload the `SetUp` method like described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207346/specify-constructor-arguments-for-a-google-test-fixture

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify constructor arguments for a Google test Fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207346/specify-constructor-arguments-for-a-google-test-fixture)